# custom std::distance implementation

Tags: c++, templates

I made "distance" template function for calculating the distance between two iterators. In the function, I divide the cases, one for random access iterator and the other. It detect well the type of iterator with iterator_traits, but I can't use this function with bidirectional iterator.

Here is my distance function

```cpp
template <typename Iter>
ptrdiff_t distance(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category type;
    ptrdiff_t dist = 0;
    if (typeid(type) == typeid(std::random_access_iterator_tag)) {
        return last - first;
    }
    for (; first != last; ++first)
        dist++;
    return (dist);
}
```

Here is main code i try to test

```cpp
int main(void)
{
    std::list<int> li;
    li.push_back(100);
    std::cout << ft::distance(li.begin(), li.end()) << std::endl;   
    return (0);
}
```

This is error message

```
./iterator.hpp:149:16: error: invalid operands to
      binary expression ('std::_List_iterator<int>' and
      'std::_List_iterator<int>')
                return (last - first);
```

I tried to make distance function without "last - first" something like below

```cpp
template <typename Iter>
static ptrdiff_t subtract(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    return (last - first);
};

template <typename Iter>
ptrdiff_t distance(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category type;
    ptrdiff_t dist = 0;
    if (typeid(type) == typeid(std::random_access_iterator_tag)) {
        return subtract(first, last);
    }
    for (; first != last; ++first)
        dist++;
    return (dist);
}
```

But it still generates the same error. How could i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `if (typeid(type) == typeid(std::random_access_iterator_tag))` needs to be `if constexpr`, so that you don't try to compile `last - first` for non-random access iterators, but `if constexpr (typeid(type) == typeid(std::random_access_iterator_tag))` does not compile.

There is, however, an [example at cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) ("second version") which shows another way to do this, like so:

```
if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<std::random_access_iterator_tag, type>)
    return last - first;
else { ...
```

This all applies to C++17 and later.  If you're looking for a solution for C++14 or earlier then the above link also shows how it can be done via tag dispatch ("first version").

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach in standard library implementations is to use the iterator tag to dispatch to a particular specialization:

```
template <class Iter, class Tag>
std::ptrdiff_t distance_impl(Iter first, Iter last, Tag) {
    std::ptrdiff_t dist = 0;
    while (first != last) {
        ++dist;
        ++first;
    }
    return dist;
}

template <class Iter>
std::ptrdiff_t distance_impl(Iter first, Iter last, std::random_access_iterator_tag) {
    return last - first;
}

template <class Iter>
std::ptrdiff_t my_distance(Iter first, Iter last) {
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category type;
    return distance_impl(first, last, type());
}
```

This is much cleaner than writing a function that contains multiple code paths that may or may not be part of the compiled version. (Yes, `constexpr if`, I'm looking at you...)